# multiple $_get parameters in a page with php

Tags: php

I created a page that have two pagination in it, one for questions one for answers.

I have links like `<a href='?questionPageNumber=7'>` as page number at bottom of questions and `<a href='?answerPageNumber=5'>` at bottom of answers.

Assuming my current url is `index.php?answerPageNumber=11`, when I click pages of questions, I loose current page.

How can I handle these with $_get parameters?

Assuming that my current url is `index.php?answerPageNumber=11` and it should become `index.php?answerPageNumber=11&questionPageNumber=4` when I click fourth page of questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include PHP when writing the links to check for get variables.  Something like this:

```
<a href="index.php?questionPageNumber=4">Questions</a>
```

would become this:

```
<?php
$link="index.php?";
if(isset($_GET["answerPageNumber"]))
    $link.="answerPageNumber=".$_GET["answerPageNumber"]."&";
$link.="questionPageNumber=4";
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Questions</a>
```